# How to Include git describe information in cordova app

Tags: cordova

I have a cordova app with an about page containing the version number from config.xml like so:

```
Version: x.y.z
```

I would like to include "git describe" information like so:

```
Version: x.y.z (vx.y.z-3-g3242341)
```

I have tried including the git info like build numbers and what not, but they seem to be meant for something else and mean different things on ios and android.

So my question is:
How do I include build metadata in an cordova app and how do I read it from the app to show in the about page. Should work on both ios and android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround that just bypasses the cordova version system completely, it simply creates a file in assets with build info and reads it from the app.

So, when my build server is about to build, I create a file:

```
echo "{\"version\":\"$(git describe)\"}" > src/assets/version.json
```

And in the app I read the file:

```
let build = await fetch('./assets/version.json')
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.ok) {
      return res.json();
    } else {
      return { version: 'Unknown' };
    }
  })
  .then((res) => res.version);
```